How to Retrieve the Access Token for Power BI API to Update Data Source Credentials?
I'm working with the Power BI REST API and trying to update the data source credentials using the following endpoint:
PATCH https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/{gatewayId}/datasources/{datasourceId} 
The request body I'm using is based on the example from the Microsoft documentation:
{
    "credentialDetails": {
        "credentialType": "OAuth2",
        "credentials": "{\"credentialData\":[{\"name\":\"accessToken\", \"value\":\"eyJ0....fwtQ\"}]}",
        "encryptedConnection": "Encrypted",
        "encryptionAlgorithm": "None",
        "privacyLevel": "None"
}

I'm having trouble understanding where to get the accessToken value for this request.
I've read through the documentation, but I'm unsure about the process for obtaining this token. Can someone guide me on how to retrieve the correct access token to use in this request?
